# Swift two delegate function for textfield

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I have two textfields in the viewController. One is "Amount", one is "Interest rate". For the "Amount", I have used a delegate function to control when they are typing, it will automatically add comma and $. Here is the code:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let oldText = textField.text! as NSString
    var newText = oldText.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string) as NSString!
    var newTextString = String(newText)

    let digits = NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet()
    var digitText = ""
    for c in newTextString.unicodeScalars {
        if digits.longCharacterIsMember(c.value) {
            digitText.append(c)
        }
    }

    let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    //        formatter.usesSignificantDigits = false
    formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.CurrencyStyle
    formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US")
    let numberFromField = (NSString(string: digitText).doubleValue) / 100

    newText = formatter.stringFromNumber(numberFromField)
    if newText.isEqualToString("$0.00") {
        newText = ""
    }

    //        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: newText as String)
    //        attributedString.addAttribute(NSKernAttributeName, value: CGFloat(0.05), range: NSRange(location: 0, length: newText.length))
    //
    //        textField.attributedText = attributedString

    textField.text = String(newText)

    return false

}
```

For the "Interest rate", I want to make the input automatically add % and limit to only one decimal dot. How can I realise it in terms of I have already had one delegate function.

Answer (score 0):

```
var amountTextField: UITextField?
var interestRateTextField: UITextField?

func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    if textField == amountTextField {
        // Do you stuff with amountTextField
    } else if textField == interestRateTextField {
        // Do you stuff with interestRateTextField
    }

    return false

}
```